# Plurality, cs 50, Why printf function prints differently outside if statement?

Tags: c, printf, cs50

I know it is not correct implementation for print_winner function (printf should be inside the if statment). However, I cannot figure out why printf prints names differently when placed outside if-statement?

**If I place printf outside if statement, here is the code and output**

Code:

```c
// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{

int maximum = candidates[0].votes;
string winner = candidates[0].name;

    for (int h = 0; h < candidate_count; h++)
        {
            if (candidates[h].votes > maximum)
                {
                    maximum  = candidates[h].votes;
                }
        }

    for (int k = 0; k < candidate_count; k++)
        {
            if (candidates[k].votes == maximum)
                {
                    winner = candidates[k].name;

                }
                printf("%s\n", winner);
```

Output:

```
~/pset3/plurality/ $ ./test sonya criss ben anbu
Number of voters: 4
Vote: ben  
Vote: ben
Vote: anbu
Vote: anbu
sonya
sonya
ben
anbu
```

**If I put printf inside if statement, here is the code and output:**

Code:

```c
// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{

int maximum = candidates[0].votes;
string winner = candidates[0].name;
    //Find maximum votes
    for (int h = 0; h < candidate_count; h++)
        {
            if (candidates[h].votes > maximum)
                {
                    maximum  = candidates[h].votes;
                    winner = candidates[h].name;

                }

        }
    //Find candidate with maximum votes
     for (int k = 0; k < candidate_count; k++)
        {
            if (candidates[k].votes == maximum)
                {
                    winner = candidates[k].name;

                    printf("%s\n", winner);
                }

        }

    return;
}
```

Output:

```
~/pset3/plurality/ $ ./plurality sonya criss ben anbu
Number of voters: 4
Vote: ben
Vote: ben
Vote: anbu
Vote: anbu
ben
anbu
```

Comment: Please [edit] and show which output you get with either version of your code and also show both versions of your code. Don't describe your code, show it.

Comment: in your first case the winner name you print is `candidates[0].name` until `if (candidates[k].votes == maximum)` become true and you assign *winner*, and you print *candidate_count* times. In the second case you only print the name of the person whose votes number equals the maximum, so ben and anbu having both 2 votes being the maximum

Comment: @bruno thank you for your response! Could you elaborate **why** in the first case winner name is printed `candidates[0].name` until `if (candidates[k].votes` becomes true?

Comment: please see my answer

Comment: @bruno, thank you! I think I got it.

Comment: @bruno, just accepted your answer. Sorry for the delay, I used stack overflow for the first time. Thank you again!

Comment: @SonyaSharova you welcome, no problem, happy stack overflow and coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your first case the winner name you print is `candidates[0].name` which is *sonia* until `if (candidates[k].votes == maximum)` become true and you reassign *winner*, and you print *candidate_count* times because unconditionally in the loop.

In the second case you only print the name of the person whose votes number equals the maximum (`if (candidates[k].votes == maximum)`is true), so only *ben* and *anbu* having both 2 votes being the maximum.

Because several persons can have the same number of votes it is useless to have the variable *winner*, you can do

```
// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
  int maximum = candidates[0].votes; /* suppose candidate_count > 0, else initialize with -1 */
  
  //Find maximum votes
  for (int h = 1; h < candidate_count; h++) /* useless to redo at index 0 */
  {
     if (candidates[h].votes > maximum)
       maximum  = candidates[h].votes;
  }

  //Find candidate(s) with maximum votes
  for (int k = 0; k < candidate_count; k++)
  {
     if (candidates[k].votes == maximum)
       puts(candidates[k].name);
  }
}
```

---

From your remark

> Could you elaborate **why** in the first case winner name is printed `candidates[0].name` until `if (candidates[k].votes` becomes true

because you initialize *winner* with `candidates[0].name;` doing :

> string winner = candidates[0].name;

and you modify *winner* **only** when `if (candidates[k].votes == maximum)`is true :

> ```
>        if (candidates[k].votes == maximum)
>            {
>                winner = candidates[k].name;
> ```